# parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed

Tags: parsing, centos, centos7

centos 7

resolv.conf

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

I also tried Google DNS values

My dns fails (Including rDNS check

When I try running

host IP

I get error

```
parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed
```

Running centos 7 and cwp, bind DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve this.

The network manager was the culprit.

I got answer from a thread at https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=8660

Answer (score 2):

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and was getting the error:

`dig: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed`

when I ran a Dig or nslookup.

```
dig example.com
```

The old /etc/resolv.conf config was still in place, which causes a conflict between the resolvconf and systemd-resolved services.

In my case /etc/resolv.conf was a symbolic link pointing to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf (the old config).

The following commands fixed it:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo systemctl restart resolvconf
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your output when you run

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

just seeing if you get something different than what you posted

Answer (score 0):

Grant's solution of changing the symbolic link worked for me.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop.  When executing:

```
host linuxfoundation.org
```

I was getting the error message:

> host: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed

After executing the commands listed in Grant's answer, I am now getting the same results as in the Linux Foundation's Intro to Linux Course on edx.org.

I would've upvoted Grant's answer but I don't have enough points.